# What is the best basketball ball material to use in concrete/cement court?

Tags: basketball, equipment, maintenance

I've been reading about the materials of basketball but since there's different types of outdoor courts I decided to ask because I want to use it on a court like this:

[Example court](https://basketballgoalstore.com/wp-content/images/court-blog-asphalt.jpg)

So, as you can see it's not that flat compared to most US outdoor courts and my biggest fear is that if I don't choose the correct material for the ball, the ball's durability will be greatly affected and I'll be wasting my money. So I'm between composite leather and rubber (leather is out of the question).

I also plan on playing almost everyday around in mornings just before noon, so I don't know if the sun will also affect the ball in a way since I live in a pretty sunny area (Mexico).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely opinion, but rubber if you want it to last, composite if you want a better feel. Both will wear out over time playing on concrete, and the grip will start to go after several months. There's not a whole lot to do about that, but rubber will keep its air better. Plus I'd personally rather play with a worn rubber ball than a worn composite - it at least retains the grip a bit better. Go to the store and try a few.